# How to Deploy Asp.net MVC3 Application to the Hosting (Web hosting Providers)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis

I am trying deploy my asp.net mvc3 application, 
here it is what i done 
1. I registered a free domain for asp.net in (somee.com) 
2. n i uploaded all project files to the server through (FTP FileZilla)
3. I added all Refernec also of Asp.net mvc3 (System.web.MVC, mvchelper, n all other assemblies also i added )

but when i run the application from internet https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9dXQ.jpg 
this error occurs  (IIS 7.5 Error)

please can u tell me how to deploy , step by step, as i am beginner really need help to learn the beauty of this language also how to include EF4.1 codefirst thing .  From basic step to end please tell me .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error looks like it could be due to the wrong framework being set for IIS within somee.com.  I've never used them but there is likely to be an option somewhere in their dashboard.  Make sure this is set to use .Net Framework 4.

If you are still having problems, try following Phil Haack's blog post on bin deploying.

http://haacked.com/archive/2011/05/25/bin-deploying-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx

Then in Visual Studio, you can right click on the project and select Publish...  From there you can select the FTP option.

Comment: I've just tried to set up an account with somee.com and get a "Could not set ACL on foder!" yellow screen of death.  It wouldn't suprise me if their servers are not configured properly.

Answer (score 1):

When your hosting provider creates the website in IIS, he has to choose the .net framework target version.

If you publish the solution using a different framework version it will generate an error.